# 3d.io combine with A-Frame - performance issue

Tags: performance, aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

Our company has tried to use 3d.io with A-Frame as a solution.

This is a floorplan sample in 3d.io

https://spaces.archilogic.com/model/Kendra_Chen/5r29uqxy?modelResourceId=69db3a0d-e1fb-4fdf-b7a8-2ce4dfe30f85&mode=edit&view-menu=camera-bookmarks&main-menu=none&logo=false

I use 3d.io combined with A-Frame, which 3d.io provide here:
(change scene id to "69db3a0d-e1fb-4fdf-b7a8-2ce4dfe30f85" )

https://appcreator.3d.io/default_setup?m=nv

I found my computer's CPU is raising to 70% and up.

I also use it as static file sample here:

https://www.istaging.com/dollhouse/artgallery/

My computer's CPU still raises to 70% and up.

Is this an A-Frame's performance issue?

If yes, how can I ask A-Frame's team to enhance this?

It's a big issue and must be resolved we think.

Is this possible to enhance? Or there are too many components to handle?

Comment: Thx for providing the URLs. We are on it, analyzing what exactly causes the CPU peaks ...

Comment: Thanks. Please help me to resolve this :(